# I have a problem with plotting a fitted line

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scipy

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy import stats

Jahresmitteltemperaturen = pd.read_csv('..Not showing because of Data reasons ..')

years = range (1979, 2022)
for year in years:
    plt.plot(years, Jahresmitteltemperaturen)
    plt.plot(years, Jahresmitteltemperaturen, 'ro')    
    plt.ylim(258,264)
    plt.title('Jahresmitteltemperaturen im Zeitraum von 1979 bis 2022 in der Arktis')
    plt.ylabel('Jahresmitteltemperaturen')
    plt.xlabel('Jahre 1979 bis 2022')
    plt.grid(True)
    slope, intercept = stats.linregress(years,Jahresmitteltemperaturen)
    Steigung = intercept + slope*years
    plt.plot(years,Steigung, color="green")
```

Trying to plot a diagramm with Data from the years 1979 to 2022 and a fitted line which shows the slope of the Data. But i get this error code "all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 43 and the array at index 1 has size 1". Do i have to do some kind of conversions from DataFrame to something else? Jahresmitteltemperaturen is a DataFrame with size 43 and float numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `Jahresmitteltemperaturen` has the same dimensions of `years`, the first problem I see is that `Jahresmitteltemperaturen` is a dataframe, thus has two dimensions, while years is a range.

You are not showing the data, but I suppose it is one entry per row, then maybe what you want to do is to plot a line for a given column of the data.

Alternatively you could try simply `Jahresmitteltemperaturen.plot()`, or more generally [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: Jahresmitteltemperaturen is struktured like this: 0,260,1,261,2,262,3,262.... and so on but in columns. Do you have any ideas how to get a line out of the Dataframe? My goal in the end is to have the temperatures of each year which works fine with the code above, but i also need a fitted line of the yearly temperatures. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: If you know how to deal with Matlab, pytorch, numpy, or some other similar slicing notation you can start with [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
For your example you would simply use `df.iloc[0,:]`, `0` meaning first row, `:` meaning all columns, if your dataframe has more than 43 rows you could simply use `df.iloc[:,0:43]`  if you want the first 43 cells ` df.iloc[0:-43:]`  to get the last 43 cells, and so on.